# Cannot create Rails3 inside Rails2 in order to upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm having a problem here. I'm trying to update my application from rails v2.3.11 to v3.0.20 and then move up from there. I've followed Ryan Bate's and other tutorials to do this however, when trying to create the rails3 app on top of the rails2 one, I get the following:

```
Tomas-MacBook-Pro:yfl_curr tomas$ rails new . --force
Can't initialize a new Rails application within the directory of another, please change to a non-Rails directory first.
Type 'rails' for help.
```

## Environment:

```
Tomas-MacBook-Pro:yfl_curr tomas$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p320 (2012-04-20 revision 35421) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]

Tomas-MacBook-Pro:yfl_curr tomas$ rails -v
Rails 3.0.20
```

I had to change the **Rakefile** and convert it to rails3 as it will not work if using v2:

```
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)
require 'rake'

SampleApp::Application.load_tasks
```

Also **boot.rb** was changed to reflect this:

```
require 'rubygems'

# Set up gems listed in the Gemfile.
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)

require 'bundler/setup' if File.exists?(ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'])
```

I'm using bundler by the way. If I run the "rake rails:upgrade:check" it works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks guys for the help!!

Regards,
Tom